# SwitchPreference dependency on two other switch preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have three `switchpreferences` in my app (say, switch1, switch2 and switch3). What I want to achieve is whenever switch1 `AND` switch2 are set to `false`, switch3 must also be set to `false` automatically. If either of switch1 or switch2 is set to `true`, switch3 should also be `true`. How can I achieve that??

Comment: when your switch 1 and 2  preference value be changed ? is it from any user intraction?

Comment: yes. on click of button and also from preferences activity. but they both  need not necessarily change together.

Comment: use local broadcast receiver in this case .when ever user interaction is perform ,fire that broadcst receiver and inside onReceive() method set switch 3 preference value with if-else condition accordingly basis of switch1 and 2.

Comment: @Radhey hey, I was able to make it work using broadcast receiver. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ur WC ..any time and every time :)

Comment: @Radhey you can post it as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps

**1) first create local broadcast receiver**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event"));
}

// Inside handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.e("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
    //perform logic here to store data etc..
  }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

**2) write any user define method like this :
     let say I want to call inside button click event ,**

```
 private void sendMessage() {
  Log.e("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event");
  // You can also include extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "Its me !!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
 //Thats it....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement onCheckChangedListener for switch1 and switch2 and add the below statement in your onCheckChanged() callback method.

```
switch3.setChecked(switch1.isChecked() || switch2.isChecked())
```